# How to read API response when a mail is successfully queued using Mailgun's official PHP SDK?

Tags: php, mailgun

I am super confused how to read API response when a mail is successfully queued using Mailgun's official PHP SDK (2.8).

```
// First, instantiate the SDK with your API credentials
$mg = Mailgun::create('key-example'); // For US servers
$mg = Mailgun::create('key-example', 'https://api.eu.mailgun.net'); // For EU servers

// Now, compose and send your message.
// $mg->messages()->send($domain, $params);
$response = $mg->messages()->send('example.com', [
  'from'    => 'bob@example.com',
  'to'      => 'sally@example.com',
  'subject' => 'The PHP SDK is awesome!',
  'text'    => 'It is so simple to send a message.'
]);

var_dump($response);
```

> ```
> //Var dump results
>
> object(Mailgun\Model\Message\SendResponse)#130 (2) {
>   ["id":"Mailgun\Model\Message\SendResponse":private]=>
>   string(52) "<201949588013742.1.5234966234A248269@mydomain.com>"
>   ["message":"Mailgun\Model\Message\SendResponse":private]=>
>   string(18) "Queued. Thank you."
> }
> ```

$response is a private object and I cannot read "Queued. Thank you." inside of it. I cannot find any relevant functions to do that in the documentation. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: That it probably provides methods to access the data in those private fields then is not what I would call a far-fetched guess, and a simple look at the source code could have confirmed that, https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php/blob/2fe264038be010ba2dacdd45eb4209db9e73f2b4/src/Model/Message/SendResponse.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the following data by this

For the ID:`$response->getId()`

For the message: `$response->getMessage()`

Cheers

Comment: God bless you man, been looking for this gem for a while now.